# How to use the JS endswith() method to check if a string variable ends with any one item from an array?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried this however it didn't work.

```
const tlds = [".com", ".net", ".it", ".edu", ".gov"]
ent/*ent is an existing variable in my code*/.endsWith(tlds)
```

Do I have to make it that it checks through each item in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to make it so that it checks through each item in the array.
You could make a for-loop to check all items in the array.
Here's my code.

```
const tlds = [".com", ".net", ".it", ".edu", ".gov"]

function endsWith(string, end) {
  for (let i = 0; i < tlds.length; i++) {
    if (string.endsWith(end[i]) === true) return true
  }
  return false
}

endsWith(ent, tlds)
```

Hope this helps(;